# How to revert pip freeze > requirements.txt?

Tags: python, linux

I already had a requirements.txt, but I used the

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This operation covered my original file. Is there any ways to revert the pip freeze?

By the way, I created a virtual environment by

```
python3 -m venv <DIR>
```

If I delete this virtual environment, will this work?

Comment: pip3 uninstall -r requirements.txt

Comment: This will not exactly revert the action.

Comment: Does pip not unistall dependencies?

Comment: If I delete the virtual environment, will that work?

Comment: backups or version control are the way to go to restore files.
It's worth learning about git even if you just use it locally in your working directory.

Apart from that. deleting and reinstalling the virtualenv is probably the easiest way to clean up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is no `pip` command to revert that. You just need to delete the venv folder and initialize new one.